# why rendering of radio button the correct with hardcoded string value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the sample model, for example:

```
public class SimpleModel
{
    public bool SomeProp { get; set; }
    public SimpleModel()
    {
        //code
    }        
}
```

and I want to render on view the property SomeProp as radio button (2 buttons), for example:

```
//code
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SomeProp, Model.SomeProp, new { @id = id }) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SomeProp, !Model.SomeProp, new { @id = id })
//code
```

When I switch value of buttons on view and save page and get the page again I see checked first radio button, always.
Any more, if I select **first** radio and save page and get page again I see checked **first** radio. If I select **second** radio and save page and get page again I see checked **first** radio.

I changed code, for example:

```
//code
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SomeProp, "true", new { @id = id }) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SomeProp, "false", new { @id = id })
//code
```

this way work correct always. If I select **first** radio and save page and get page again I see checked **first** radio. If I select **second** radio and save page and get page again I see checked **second** radio.

why rendering of radio button the correct with hardcoded string value?

Comment: What's being rendered as a result of the first example?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ I see two radio buttons, but the first radio checked always

Comment: Show us the mark-up. I wrote something similar yesterday and opted for the second example, I'm not sure you'd ever choose the first.

Comment: you should have different id of both, same id causes invalid html

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ excuse me, but I don't understand you not sure in what?

Comment: and in first example you are using bool and in second its string

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yes, Ids are different. Id change between of code for radio buttons. I'm not say about it, sorry. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try  Model.SomeProp.ToString() .

Comment: thank you for answer, but how your answer can help me?

Comment: @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SomeProp, Model.SomeProp.ToString(), new { @id = id })

Comment: my question not about how render the bool value in string.
but thanks anyway